# Haskell How to count and group strings in a list

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell and need some help in figuring out logic for this function. I only want to do the problem using functions in standard prelude and recursion if possible.

So I have a list of things eg:

```
["Abhi", "Stack","how", "Abhi"]
```

Goal is to convert this into list of pair with a count and list item
output : `[("Abhi", 2), ("Stack",1)..]`

I came up with the following functions

```
countList :: [String] -> [(Int,String)]
countList [] = []
countList xss@(x:xs) = (x,checkCount x xss) : countList xs

checkCount :: String -> [String] -> Int
checkCount _ [] = 0
checkCount str (x:xs) | str == x = 1 + checkCount str xs
                      | otherwise = 0 + checkCount str xs
```

The output I get from this is :

```
[("Abhi",2), ("Stack",1), ("how",1),("Abhi",1)]
```

Notice how the last item is Abhi, 1. I can't find a recursive way to fix it.

Comment: It might be better to sort it using `Data.List.sort`, then you can use `Data.List.group`, followed by `map (\w -> (head w, length w))`.

Comment: Data.List will do what I am looking for but really want to do with standard prelude functions only.

Comment: In order to do it recursively, you'll also have to keep track of which names you've already seen.  It might be best to emulate the `Data.Map.Map` structure using `[(String, Int)]`, you can use `lookup` and you could write a custom `update` function to work with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with just `Prelude` functions and recursion, you can emulate a `Map` structure using a list of tuples.  This will be less efficient, but it avoids having to use other modules.  The core of the algorithm is just writing a function that updates a value in a `Map`:

```
type Map k v = [(k, v)]  -- Simulate Data.Map.Map

update :: Eq k => k -> (Maybe v -> v) -> Map k v -> Map k v
update k fv [] = [(k, fv Nothing)]
update k fv ((k', v'):rest)
    = if k == k'
        then (k', fv $ Just v') :             rest
        else (k',           v') : update k fv rest
```

This function just says to walk down the `Map`, if it finds the element then update it and stop, otherwise keep trying.  If it hits the end of the `Map` then call the updating function with `Nothing` to produce a default value.

Next, we can use this to build up a `Map k Int` for this specific case:

```
countOccurs :: Eq k => [k] -> Map k Int
countOccurs = foldr go []
    where
        go k = update k updtr
        updtr Nothing  = 1
        updtr (Just i) = i + 1
```

But we can inline `updtr` to be just `maybe 1 (+1)`:

```
countOccurs = foldr go []
    where
        go k = update k (maybe 1 (+1))
```

And since `go` is simple enough, let's just inline it using `flip`, or equivalently using backticks to make `update` infix:

```
countOccurs = foldr (`update` maybe 1 (+1)) []
```

We don't even need to put parens around `maybe 1 (+1)` since it is now seen as an argument to an operator.

---

As a demo:

```
> countOccurs $ words "Abhi Stack how Abhi"
[("Abhi", 2), ("how", 1), ("Stack", 1)]

> countOccurs [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem in your code is the snippet, `countList xs` - it means you are not counting occurrences of each `x` in the full list but rather one that diminishes with each call of `countList`.

Why not add a parameter to your original `countList` of the form `[(Int,String)]`- let's call it, `result`.

As you traverse the list to count, pass `x` and `result` to the `checkCount` function, which in this case will traverse `result`. If it finds a match for `x`, it will increase the count for that `x` in `result`. If it does not find `x`, it will insert `(1,x)` in `result`.

Comment: I fixed it afterwards.

Comment: @AbhinavGogna you mean in your answer? cool! Should I leave my remark since it refers to your posted code and could be helpful to someone?

Comment: Please leave it. It can be useful for someone else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

bheklilr - Thanks for your awesome answer and explanation. Since I am a newb in Haskell it was little over my head in the beginning.

Anyway, I found another way to do it. I changed my approach to list recursion with index. It may not be optimal but at least works. Here it goes

Initially I was iterating using list values, so, I couldn't account for values that were removed. I decided to keep the list as is and iterate using indices.

countList' is a wrapper, so, I don't have to pass list with its length.

```
countList' :: [String] -> [(Int,String)]
countList' [] = []
countList' lst = countListWithIndex (length' lst) lst
```

CheckCount function was unchanged

```
checkCount :: String -> [String] -> Int
checkCount _ [] = 0
checkCount str (x:xs) | str == x = 1 + checkCount str xs
                      | otherwise = 0 + checkCount str xs
```

This function gets the number of repetitions in the list based on the index.

```
countListWithIndex :: Int -> [String] -> [(Int, String)]
countListWithIndex 0 _ = []
countListWithIndex n str = (checkCount string str, string) : countListWithIndex (n-1) str
                             where string = dataAt (n-1) str
```

Function to find data in a list using index

```
dataAt :: Int -> [a] -> a
dataAt _ [] = error "Empty List!"
dataAt y (x:xs)  | y <= 0 = x
                 | otherwise = dataAt (y-1) xs
```

Simple function to calculate length of a list

```
length' :: [a] -> Int
length' [] = 0
length' (_:xs) = 1 + length' xs
```

Also, I know the list still has duplicate values. I may have to write another function to remove them. Baby steps :)

Anyway would love to know feedback.

Answer (score 0):

What happen on your function `countList` (checkCount is fine) is on this line `countList xss@(x:xs) = (x,checkCount x xss) : countList xs`. When you call recursivly to `countList` you lost the head `x`. So, the first recursive call will be like:

```
("Abni",2) : countList ["Stack","how", "Abhi"]
```

When it get to the next `"Abni"`, there will be just one.

You need to keep the original list. Try this:

```
countList' :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
countList' [] = []
countList' (s:ss) = fun s ss (s:ss) []
    where fun s ss sss acc
        | null ss   = (s, checkCount' s sss):acc
        | otherwise = fun (head ss) (tail ss) sss $ (s, checkCount' s sss):acc
```

The above is with tail recursion. More simple:

```
countList :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
countList [] = []
countList ss = hack ss ss
    where hack (x:xs) sss
        | null xs   = [(x, checkCount x sss)]
        | otherwise = (x, checkCount x sss) : (hack xs sss)
```

Comment: Nice! you passed the same list twice in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with a series of helper functions. I assume that extra verbosity is OK since the solution needs to use only Prelude ... a concise solution would be a direct application of helper functions that already exist in either `Data.Map` or `Data.List`. Probably some of what I have can be made shorter using `fold` and so on...

```
countByGroup :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
countByGroup [] = []
countByGroup xs = let (c:cs) = toCounts xs
                  in mergeCounts [c] cs

toCounts :: [a] -> [(a, Int)]
toCounts xs = [(x, 1) | x <- xs]

mergeCounts :: (Eq a) => [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
mergeCounts = mergeCounts' []

mergeCounts' :: (Eq a) => [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
mergeCounts' acc [] [] = acc
mergeCounts' acc (l:ls) [] = case ls of
    [] -> acc ++ [l]
    otherwise -> acc ++ mergeCounts [l] ls
mergeCounts' acc [] (r:rs) = case rs of
    [] -> acc ++ [r]
    otherwise -> acc ++ mergeCounts [r] rs
mergeCounts' acc (l:ls) rs = 
    let rSum   = sum [snd r | r <- rs, fst r == fst l]
        lSum   = sum [snd x | x <- ls, fst x == fst l]
        newAcc = acc ++ [(fst l, snd l + rSum + lSum)]
        newRs  = [r | r <- rs, fst r /= fst l]
        newLs  = [x | x <- ls, fst x /= fst l]
    in  mergeCounts' newAcc newLs newRs
```

For example:

```
*Main> countByGroup ["a", "b", "a", "b"]
[("a",2),("b",2)]
*Main> countByGroup ["Abhi", "Stack","how", "Abhi"]
[("Abhi",2),("Stack",1),("how",1)]
*Main> countByGroup ["Abhi", "Stack","how", "Abhi", "how"]
[("Abhi",2),("Stack",1),("how",2)]
*Main> countByGroup ["Abhi", "Abhi"]
[("Abhi",2)]
*Main> countByGroup []
[]
*Main> countByGroup ["how", "Abhi", "Abhi", "how", "how"]
[("how",3),("Abhi",2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to do this by Prelude, but as I searched for a Solutions with HashMap and I can't found a good solution, I want to share my solution with people that can use HashMap in their code:

I got help from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179828/updating-items-in-a-haskell-map-how).

```haskell
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as MP
l = ["a", "a", "v", "b", "b", "b"]
result = foldl (\mp x -> MP.insertWith (+) x 1 mp)  MP.empty l
```

the result is:

```haskell
fromList [("b",3),("v",1),("a",2)]
```

and you can lookup a key by

```haskell
MP.lookup "a" result
```

and its output will be

```haskell
Just 2
```