# Updating items in a Haskell Map, how?

Tags: dictionary, haskell

I am new to Haskell and am trying to figure out a sensible
way to write to Maps (in preparation for solving a particular
Euler project problem)

I hope to write a function that would populate
a Map with a record. But I can't get it to work.

`let` seems to create local variables instead of
treating `smap` as a global.

There must be a some way to do this.

My code:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map 

smap = Map.fromList [("cocoa",23)]


newdata str n = do  
   let cpy  = Map.insert str n  smap
   cpy 

main = do
     let smap = newdata "pennywise" 16  
     let smap = newdata "krusty" 18
```

*update from comments:* Later on I want to count how many ways a right angle triangle is equal to a perimeter. So I thought a Map would be a good way to store the distribution counts e.g. p10 -> 5 ways, p15 -> 6 ways etc. So as the program runs, it would increment already discovered perimeters values.

Comment: Variables are immutable, you can't really “update” them. Once assigned, they do not change. What you have right now can be replaced with: `smap = Map.fromList [("cocoa", 23), ("pennywise", 16), ("krusty", 18)]` Can you illustrate why this is not enough?

Comment: Hi Norrius, Later on I want to count how many ways a right angle triangle is equal to a perimeter. So I thought a Map would be a good way to store the distribution counts e.g. p10 -> 5 ways, p15 -> 6 ways etc. So as the program runs, it would increment already discovered perimeters values.

Comment: You can always create a new map with `Map.insert` and use it instead.

Comment: I thought I was doing that by assigning the Map.insert to cpy. Is there something I am missing.

Comment: Don't try to reassign it, just use it, e.g. in recursion do the next function call with it. You can try writing the actual code that does the count first to see where you need it.

Comment: Thanks Norrius, I'll give that a try...!

Comment: Also, a `do` expression is not simply a trapdoor into some mutable version of Haskell. It's syntactic sugar for monadic expressions, which simply doesn't apply here.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `do` in `newdata` for some reason, may I ask you what the reason is?

Answer (score 10):

You can not modify a `Map` in place (since Haskell is a purely functional language) but you can create a new one which is almost equal to the old map, except for a few entries that have been modified.

(Don't worry too much about efficiency: counter-intuitively, the new `Map` does not require a full copy of the old one.)

For instance, suppose we want to count the frequencies of each character in a string. Let's write a function which, given a char `c`, increments its count stored inside the `Map`

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

countChar :: Char -> M.Map Char Int -> M.Map Char Int
countChar c oldMap = newMap
   where
   newMap = M.insertWith (+) c 1 oldMap
```

The `newMap` variable is not needed, it is shown above for clarity.

The function `insertWith` makes the new map so that at index `c` it stores 1, if there is no value in the old map, or `1 + x` if there is a previous value `x` in the old map.

To handle a full string, we use recursion:

```
countString :: String -> M.Map Char Int
countString ""     = M.empty
countString (c:cs) = countChar c (countString cs)
```

Small test in GHCi:

```
> countString "here's an example"
fromList [(' ',2),('\'',1),('a',2),('e',4),('h',1),('l',1),('m',1)
         ,('n',1),('p',1),('r',1),('s',1),('x',1)]
```

For a more advanced solution, `countString` could also be rewritten as a fold, if wanted. Using a left strict fold would also improve efficiency.

```
countString = foldl' (flip countChar) M.empty
```

One could even use a state monad to avoid passing around the `Map`. If you are learning Haskell, don't worry about this, and start by learning how to solve these kinds of tasks using recursion, pattern matching, and a few library functions for `Map`s.

Comment: I don't much care for `insertWith`: it's too hard to remember the order the arguments get passed to the combining function. If you need a bit more than `insert`, I think `alter` offers a nicer API.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell is a pure functional language. You can not modify a variable in place. But with state monad and lens, Haskell can be the best imperative language. Here is an example.

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Map
import Control.Monad.State

example :: State (Map String Int) Int
example = do
    -- set value
    at "pennywise" ?= 16
    at "krusty" ?= 18
    -- get value
    Just krusty <- use $ at "krusty"
    pure krusty

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let r = evalState example empty
    print r
```

Lens provides a common interface to operate with data structures like Map, that's why I love it.

Another example:

```
countString :: String -> Map Char Int
countString str = flip execState empty $
    forM_ str $ \c -> 
        at c %= Just . maybe 1 (+1)

-- countString "asasdsas"
-- fromList [('a',3),('d',1),('s',4)]
```